# Failing rspec test on silly blocks

Tags: ruby, rspec, repeater, block

Hello please review my code and tell me what is wrong because it fails rspec but works on repl.it. I don't understand the feedback from rspec. 
Failure/Error: n.should == 3
Expect: 3
Got: 0 (using==)

My code:

```
def repeater(x=0)
  if x == 0
    return yield
  else
    x.times do |n|
      n += 1
    end
  end
end
```

It pass the first test of the following:

```
 describe "repeater" do
    it "executes the default block" do
      block_was_executed = false
      repeater do
        block_was_executed = true
      end
      block_was_executed.should == true
    end
    it "executes the default block 3 times" do
      n = 0
      repeater(3) do
        n += 1
      end
      n.should == 3
    end

    it "executes the default block 10 times" do
      n = 0
      repeater(10) do
        n += 1
      end
      n.should == 10
    end

  end
```

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work on the console neither, since `n` is defined within the block scope of the `repeater` method. What you're seeing on the console is the value returned by the `times` block, but if you inspect the value of n, it will still be zero.

If you change your repeater method to:

```
def repeater(x=0)
  if x == 0
    return yield
  else
    x.times do |n|
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

Then the specs will pass, since the reference to `n` will be given by the calling context

Comment: Your answer works like a charm, but I don't understand where you instruct it to += 1.

Comment: You instructed it in the spec file :-) `repeater(3) do; n += 1; end` and `repeater(10) do; n += 1; end` tell the repeater method what to do.

Comment: Is there a way to refactor? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rspec is telling you what is wrong. You expect n to be 3 but it is 0.

Your spec:

```
n = 0
repeater(3) do
  n +=1
end
n.should == 3
```

I'm not sure why you are passing a block as it is completely ignored, but maybe you are testing that the block is ignored and your function does as is expected.

Your function if given a non-zero value will make a weird loop. The loop itself doesn't do anything and the value produced by the loop with be `x`.

So your call to repeater will return whatever value was passed in if it is non-zero. However that doesn't matter in your spec since you ignore the return value.

So you basically set n to 0, don't do anything with it and then expect it to equal 3 which of course will fail.

Comment: I have zero coding experience and have spent about 40 hrs learning Ruby so far, there is so much basics that I don't have. Most importantly I still can't see the "big picture" in coding, thus the elementary mistake. I hope you understand :)

Comment: I don't even understand where to enter the value for n. I assume n is the return value of the default block, like repeater(3) {5} returns 8? Thank you for being patient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to your problem.  Blocks and yields are powerful.  Still learning to grasp it myself.

def repeater(num=0, &block)

```
return block.call if num==0

   num.times do |n|
      block.call
   end
```

end

If you want to refractor into one line.  See below

def repeater(num=0, &block)

```
  return block.call if num==0; num.times { |n| block.call}
```

end